# What is a good sample solrconfig.xml for django-haystack?

Tags: django, solr, spell-checking, django-haystack

I am building out a solr instance for django, but the example provided from solr is super verbose, with many things that are not relevant to haystack. A sample with spelling suggestions, morelikethis, and faceting, without the extra stuff that haystack doesn't use would go a long way to helping me understand what is needed and what isn't.

Comment: Why don't you take the example solrconfig.xml, remove all the request handlers but the ones you do really want? If you don't know anything about solr, I would advice you to read its excelent 10 minute tutorial (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html). Keep in mind that is almost impossible to use a search engine without knowing it well, in most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this one](https://gist.github.com/1438211).  I works and fits my needs, except for morelikethis that wasn't that good and I don't use faceting.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use an "out of the box" solr config.  You should understand your search requirements and write a schema and config that matches.

This is one of the drawbacks of the way people use haystack.  They rely on the default behaviour which is very rarely the optimum behaviour for solr.

Answer (score -4):

You shouldn't need to write an xml file - one of the benefits of Haystack is that it does that for you. Once your searchindex classes are defined, just run `./manage.py build_solr_schema` and copy the resulting xml to your solrconfig file.

Comment: build_solr_schema makes the schema.xml file, not the solrconfig.xml file. I even have a little one-liner when I update my schema.xml:

`sudo rm /usr/share/tomcat6/solr/conf/schema.xml && sudo sh -c "python manage.py build_solr_schema >> /usr/share/tomcat6/solr/conf/schema.xml"`

but not the answer to the question :-(